# Convert data frame into zoo time series constructe with a chron date time object of month/day/year hr:min:sec (i.e. 01/15/19 00:06:00) in r?

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to use the "StreamMetabolism' package in R to calculating stream metabolism (https://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/StreamMetabolism/StreamMetabolism.pdf). In order to run the codes, dates need to be in a specific format that I am struggling to create.

I have a csv file in the following format:

```html
structure(list(DateTime = structure(1:18, .Label = c("(01/15/2019 00:06:00)", 
"(01/15/2019 00:21:00)", "(01/15/2019 00:36:00)", "(01/15/2019 00:51:00)", 
"(01/15/2019 01:06:00)", "(01/15/2019 01:21:00)", "(01/15/2019 01:36:00)", 
"(01/15/2019 01:51:00)", "(01/15/2019 02:06:00)", "(01/15/2019 02:21:00)", 
"(01/15/2019 02:36:00)", "(01/15/2019 02:51:00)", "(01/15/2019 03:06:00)", 
"(01/15/2019 03:21:00)", "(01/15/2019 03:36:00)", "(01/15/2019 03:51:00)", 
"(01/15/2019 04:06:00)", "(01/15/2019 04:21:00)"), class = "factor"), 
Temp = c(16.947, 16.862, 16.752, 16.735, 16.65, 16.608, 16.523, 
16.455, 16.412, 16.361, 16.293, 16.25, 16.267, 16.216, 16.148, 
16.114, 16.054, 16.046), DO = c(8.45, 8.429, 8.425, 8.379, 
8.38, 8.358, 8.354, 8.344, 8.334, 8.323, 8.329, 8.314, 8.291, 
8.29, 8.298, 8.29, 8.296, 8.289)), .Names = c("DateTime", 
"Temp", "DO"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I want to convert above data into time-series format(month/day/year hr:min:sec, i.e. 01/15/19 00:06:00) and output should look like :

```html
    Temp    DO
(01/15/2019 00:06:00)   16.947  8.45
(01/15/2019 00:21:00)   16.862  8.429
(01/15/2019 00:36:00)   16.752  8.425
(01/15/2019 00:51:00)   16.735  8.379
(01/15/2019 01:06:00)   16.65   8.38
(01/15/2019 01:21:00)   16.608  8.358
(01/15/2019 01:36:00)   16.523  8.354
(01/15/2019 01:51:00)   16.455  8.344
(01/15/2019 02:06:00)   16.412  8.334
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you add your data using `dput` ? See here on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi Ronak, I have added data as dput, could you please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mdy_hms` to convert `DateTime` column to `POSIXct` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% mutate(DateTime = mdy_hms(DateTime))
df
#              DateTime   Temp    DO
#1  2019-01-15 00:06:00 16.947 8.450
#2  2019-01-15 00:21:00 16.862 8.429
#3  2019-01-15 00:36:00 16.752 8.425
#4  2019-01-15 00:51:00 16.735 8.379
#5  2019-01-15 01:06:00 16.650 8.380
#6  2019-01-15 01:21:00 16.608 8.358
#7  2019-01-15 01:36:00 16.523 8.354
#8  2019-01-15 01:51:00 16.455 8.344
#9  2019-01-15 02:06:00 16.412 8.334
#10 2019-01-15 02:21:00 16.361 8.323
#11 2019-01-15 02:36:00 16.293 8.329
#12 2019-01-15 02:51:00 16.250 8.314
#13 2019-01-15 03:06:00 16.267 8.291
#14 2019-01-15 03:21:00 16.216 8.290
#15 2019-01-15 03:36:00 16.148 8.298
#16 2019-01-15 03:51:00 16.114 8.290
#17 2019-01-15 04:06:00 16.054 8.296
#18 2019-01-15 04:21:00 16.046 8.289
```

Using base R, you can do the same by :

```
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format = '(%m/%d/%Y %T)', tz = 'UTC')
```

You can convert it to time series by doing :

```
xts::xts(df[-1], order.by = df[[1]])
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for this. It works well. However, my issue is in order to run a Specific R package called "StreamMetabolism' time format should be month/day/year
hr:min: sec (08/18/70 23:15:00). This is where I am struggling, authors of the package use function called 'read.production' . but it didn't work well for me. can you provide any assistance? (more details available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/StreamMetabolism/StreamMetabolism.pdf)

Comment: Which function do you want to apply from that package? You can have use `format` to get data timestamp in the format specified but it would be of class "character". Perhaps, better to ask a new question mentioning the details about the function that you want to apply.

Comment: Hi Ronak, I need to use a function called 'read.production' in 'streamMetabolism' package. As you suggested I have asked a new question. Could you please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to modify the `DateTime` column without creating a new one, you could try this:

```
df$DateTime <- strptime(df$DateTime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

(where `df` is the name of the data frame you are using)

The `strptime` function gives all the dates  the format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but still got error as follow:Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, VAR2, value = list(sec = NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 1056 rows, data has 96

Comment: Use instead `df$DateTime <- strptime(df$DateTime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`